# ember cli simple auth devise last version 0.8.0-beta.1

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I am trying to set up ember cli simple auth devise in my app, actually I found many examples and similar issues but still not able to solve a problem that I am fighting many hours, it is the last version of the addon 0.8.0-beta.1, the authentication works perfect but when I try to visit a page under a token authorization, the token is not sending in the header:
[image]

The thing I am thinking which causes this is the devise authorization in the config file, I have it the same described in the doc:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise'
}
```

I have the whole code in this [repo](https://github.com/simo163/ember-cli-simple-auth-example), if you could give a feedback it will be really appreciated!!!

Updated 20/04/2015:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
    authorizer: 'simple-auth-authorizer:devise',
    crossOriginWhitelist: ['*']
}

# config/application.rb 
# rack-cors configuration in the server side 
config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
  allow do
    origins "*"
    resource "*",
      :headers => :any,
      :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
      :credentials => true
  end
end
```

result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your API maybe running on a different host or port and you forgot configuring the `crossOriginWhitelist`?

Comment: @marcoow yes I have a rails api configured with apache and passenger. i tried crossOriginWhitelist using rack-cors but no way. could u recommend a tutorial or a repo with an example it will be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your API is running on a different host/port you need to configure Ember Simple Auth's `crossOriginWhitelist` and list the API's origin there so Ember Simple Auth will inject the `Authorization` header. This is a security measure that makes sure that Auth tokens aren't sent with every request all over the Internet.

Comment: yes I configured crossOriginWhitelist too and in the api I installed rack-cors, but seems like all my request got responded with type text/plain (I guess that the api responds with text and not anymore with json), also it said that multiple domaines were used, I update my post with configuration and the error. am I doing something wrong?

Comment: like the error message says, the CORS response is wrong so that the server cannot send the cross-origin request.

Comment: that's true, I have no idea why the server sends twice access-control-allow-origin. If I am using apache and passenger does it make sense to use rack-cors? since in virtualhost configuration the header could be set up as well.

Comment: Yes, probably simpler to set it up in Apache's config

Comment: awesome, I finally could fix it by configuring apache (I had two configuration files of my project, that why origins in headers were sent twice) and by rack-cors as well. Thanks Marco for keeping me updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody facing the same issue, as I am working with apache passenger, I found two apache config files of the actual project I am working on, that why origins was sent twice. If you're using passenger I'd suggest to forget about rack-cors and configure it in apache, I found it a clean way.

```
# add these lines in your apache config file into VirtualHost (or Directory must also work) 
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "*"
Header set access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Hope this helps.